# Underline entre duas variáveis

Tags: sintaxe, shell, shell-script

Tenho o seguinte código num arquivo .sh:

```
echo "$pasta/Dados/$MA/$ano\_$mes/$tabela"
```

Com todas as variáveis setadas corretamente. Porém, ai rodar o script, o echo resulta em

```
data-integration/Dados/MA1/2015\_11/HT_MA1_ESS_SEG
```

Enquanto eu gostaria que o resultado fosse

```
data-integration/Dados/MA1/2015_11/HT_MA1_ESS_SEG
```

Existe alguma outra sintaxe para essa situação?
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é você colocar o nome das variáveis entre chaves `{}`:

```
#!/bin/sh

pasta="data-integration"
MA="MA1"
ano="2015"
mes="11"
tabela="HT_MA1_ESS_SEG"

echo "$pasta/Dados/$MA/${ano}_${mes}/$tabela"
```

Executando o programa acima, a saída é:

`data-integration/Dados/MA1/2015_11/HT_MA1_ESS_SEG`

<sub>testado com GNU bash, version 4.3.42</sub>

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!